# Can I use Anaconda on TextMate

Tags: macos, python-3.x, textmate, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda with Python 3.4. How can I use that version on TextMate?

I tried adding `~/anaconda/bin` at the beginning of the `PATH` variable, but it doesn't work.

When I try to run a program I get `Program exited with code #1 after 0.00 seconds` and no output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Anaconda Python 2, and found a couple ways to do this.

First note that the tilde shortcut ( ~ ) doesn't work everywhere, and as you found not in text mate variables.  Usually you have to use the full path  e.g. `/Users/youruserid/Anaconda/bin/`

- Add the path above to your PATH variable in TextMate
- set a TM_PYTHON variable to use in text mate, again using the full path to the binary you want to use
- use the Shebang at the top of your script pointing to anaconda python
  `#!/Users/youruserid/Anaconda/bin/python`
- make a symbolic link in /usr/local/bin to anaconda
  `ln -s /Users/youruserid/Anaconda/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python`

  this will affect more than TextMate, and requires `/usr/local/bin` to be in your 
  path

Also some use the link `/usr/local/bin/python3` for python 3.x to distinguish between python 3 and 2.